# ASP.Net MVC3 Ajax interval post

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm currently trying to do the same function the Ajax.BeginForm helper does but instead of doing it through a input submit tag doing it on a set interval of about 30 seconds.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "shipmentTable", OnComplete = "OnSuccess"}))
```

Works perfectly but can't seem to translate it into a working jquery.ajax call.  The post controller has two arguments, a minDate and a maxDate.  The Raw URL being something like Home/Shippments?minDate=arg1&maxDate=arg2.  I have tried may variations of something along the lines of:

```
setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/Shipping',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: OnSuccess
        });
    }, 30000);
```

With no luck.  Just wanted to see if anyone could help me out. Cheers.

**UPDATE:**
This seems to work good just had to change the parameters in the controller to just the accept FormCollection only.

```
setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        url: '/Home/Shipping',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: OnSuccess
    });
}, 30000);
```

I seems like all the the answers worked pretty well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a string to the success function. Pass the function itself which will be something like this:

```
function OnSuccess(ajaxReturnedData)
{
 alert("success");
}

setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/Shipping',
            data : { param1 : "value1", param2: "value2" },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: OnSuccess
        });
    }, 30000);
```

Or combine it:

```
setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/Shipping',
            data : { param1 : "value1", param2: "value2" },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(ajaxReturnedData){
                alert("success");
            }
        });
    }, 30000);
```

If you got firebug, you can see the status of the Ajax call, what does it return? Any error code or success?

Comment: This seems to work but I doesn't return the form data with it.

Comment: use at the `data` part the following line: `data : $("form").serialize(),`

Comment: Similar question to the answer by Joe Tuskan will I need to just put my form data within a plain <form></form> tag or use Html.Begin() maybe?

Comment: Just within the `<form>` tags, or you can define the input fields by this: `data : { "input1" : $("[name=input1name]").val(), "input2" : $("[name=input2name]").val() },`

Comment: Looks like most of the answers worked but you helped me through it the most so you got the accepted answer.  Found also that Ajax.BeginForm() with a setInterval on $("form").submit works great as well.

Answer (score 2):

You will need something like [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

```
setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#formId').serialize(),
        url: '/Home/Shipping',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: OnSuccess
    });
}, 30000);
```

to add the values of `minDate` and `maxDate`.

Comment: Would have have to create my own form tag? Do I use the Html.BeginForm() instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
setInterval(function () {
        $.post('/Home/Shipping',$("form").serialize(), function(data){
  //success
}), 30000);
```